# How to make connection between controller and view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have been working on it and didn't get a proper solution.what i want to do is i have a function in controller that gets data from model .
this is my controller function:

```
function index() {

    $data['results1'] = $this->RetrieveData_model->GetData();

    $this->load->view('ViewData',$data);


    }
```

i want to access that $data['results1'] variable in my editview to auto fill the fields.this is my view:

```
<div id="container">
            <?php echo form_open('insert_ctrl/updateData/'); ?>
            <h1>Update Data Into Database Using CodeIgniter</h1><hr/> 
            <?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
                <CENTER><h3 style="color:green;">Data updated successfully</h3></CENTER><br>
            <?php } ?>
                <?php echo form_label('Student Name :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dname'); ?><br />
            <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dname', 'name' => 'dname', 'value' => $results1[0]->Student_Name)); ?><br />

            <?php echo form_label('Student Email :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('demail'); ?><br />
            <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'demail', 'name' => 'demail', 'value' => $results1[0]->Student_Email)); ?><br />

            <?php echo form_label('Student Mobile No. :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dmobile'); ?><br />
            <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dmobile', 'name' => 'dmobile', 'placeholder' => '10 Digit Mobile No.', 'value' => $results[0]->Student_Mobile)); ?><br />

            <?php echo form_label('Student Address :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('daddress'); ?><br />
            <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'daddress', 'name' => 'daddress','value' => $results1[0]->Student_Address)); ?><br />

        <?php echo form_hidden( array('id' => 'studentId', 'name' => 'studentId','value' => $results1[0]->Student_id) ); ?><br />

            <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?><br/>
           <div id="fugo">

            </div>
     <button type="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo base_url();?>ViewData_ctrl/index'">
            View data Record
     </button>

        </div>
```

when i accessed that "result1" in view it is giving error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: results1

Filename: views/EditView.php

Line Number: 16

Backtrace:

File: D:\dev\htdocs\CI2\application\views\EditView.php
Line: 16
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\dev\htdocs\CI2\application\controllers\insert_ctrl.php
Line: 104
Function: view

File: D:\dev\htdocs\CI2\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Please help how can i solve this as i am new to Codeignitor..

Comment: can you please tell me in your controller shows the value or not?

Comment: check this var_dump($data); in your controller

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your controller you given wrong view name

```
function index() {

    $data['results1'] = $this->RetrieveData_model->GetData();

    $this->load->view('EditView',$data);


    }
```

and your view Var_dump your array.

```
 <?php
var_dump($results1);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

check your file name

```
  $this->load->view('ViewData',$data); 
  // change to
    $this->load->view('EditView',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an other mistake in your editview file: 
you have skipped "1" in $results1 array it may help you out

```
$results1[0]->Student_Mobile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer.you wil get the result very easily

in controller

```
function index() {

    $data['results1'] = $this->RetrieveData_model->GetData();

    $this->load->view('ViewData',$data);


    }
```

in view page

```
<?php
foreach($results1 as $row)
{
    echo $row->id; //echo your fields like this
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In view page you can use

```
 <?php echo form_open('insert_ctrl/updateData/'); ?>
    <?php
    foreach($results1 as $row)
    {

   //try this to get details

    echo $row->Student_Address;
    echo $row->Student_id;


    //or try this        

    echo $row['Student_Address'];
    echo $row['Student_id'];
    }
    ?>
```